# Creating a Minstack using ES6

Tags: javascript, stack

I am attempting to produce the solution for the great MinStack problem and I am trying to write it using ES6 notation. I have been able to accomplish the problem using ES5 class notation and I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. For some reason in my push method in my MinStack, the value I pass in becomes undefined. Thus when I print out min._min.storage all of the values are undefined. Any help is greatly appreciated and happy coding!

```
class Stack {
    constructor(capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.count = 0;
    this.storage = {};
  }

   push(value) {
     console.log('here is this and your value', this, value) //value is undefined when _.min.push(value) is called
    if (this.count === this.capacity) {
      return 'Max capacity already reached. Remove element before adding a new one.';
    } else {
      this.storage[this.count++] = value;
    }
 }
// Time complexity: 0(1);

  pop() {
    var poppedElement = this.storage[--this.count];
    delete this.storage[this.count];
    if (this.count < 0) {
      this.count = 0;
    }
    return poppedElement;
  };
  // Time complexity: 0(1)

  peek() {
    return this.storage[this.count - 1];
  };
  // Time complexity: 0(1)

  count() {
    return this.count;
};
}
// Time complexity: 0(1)


//1.
class MinStack extends Stack {
  constructor(capacity) {
    super(capacity);
    this._min = new Stack(capacity);
  }

  push(value) {
    if (this.count < this.capacity) {
      if (value < this._min.peek()) {
        this._min.push(value);
      } else {
        this._min.push(this._min.peek());
      }
      this.storage[this.count++] = value;
      return this.count;
    }
  }

  pop() {
    const poppedElement = this.storage[--this.count];
    this._min.pop();
    delete this.storage[this.count];
    if (this.count < 0) {
      this.count = 0;
    }
    return poppedElement;
  }

  min() {
    return this._min.peek();
  }

  peek() {
    return this.storage[this.count - 1];
  }

  count() {
    return this.count;
  }
}

var min = new MinStack(6);
min.push(1);
min.push(2)
min.push(1)
min.push(0)
min.push(3)
min.push(5)
console.log(min);
console.log(min.min()) //undefined
```

Comment: This is because your `this._min.peek()` function returns undefined at first. You have to ensure your storage has at least one value.

Comment: @Simon Sorry for responding to this so late! Thank you so much for the help!